# Go ignores HTTP_PROXY environment variable

Tags: go, environment-variables

I read all over the internet, that Go reads `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable and set proxy for default client. However, it is not working for me and I don't know why.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, Go was 1.16, so I upgraded to 1.17 but it still the same.

I have the program below and I execute this in terminal: `HTTP_PROXY="http://localhost:8000" go run req.go`
I see that first `Println` prints out correct value, but proxy is not used.

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("HTTP_PROXY"))
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Get("http://localhost:8090/vm/1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

If I modify the code, and set proxy explicitly, it works.

```golang
u, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8000")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(u)},
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging in the source code I have found the main reason and also a workaround. It is commented behavior, but quite deep. Source [opensource.google/x/net/http/httpproxy/proxy.go line 118](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/internal-branch.go1.17-vendor:http/httpproxy/proxy.go;l=118) and on [line 181](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/internal-branch.go1.17-vendor:http/httpproxy/proxy.go;l=181) is exact `if` which is responsible.

The issue is, that `HTTP_PROXY` is ignored when the request has URL **localhost** or **127.x.x.x**. But you can easily add custom URI to `/etc/hosts` or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1    localserver.loc
```

Then all requests must go to `localserver.loc:8090` not `localhost:8090`. And it will work like a charm.

Comment: This behaviour is stupid and makes local debugging just needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a NO_PROXY variable set to "localhost", which is respected by the DefaultTransport.

When explicitely setting a Proxy with http.ProxyURL(), this proxy is used regardless of NO_PROXY.

Comment: I added to `main()` also this line `fmt.Println(os.Getenv("NO_PROXY"))` which prints out nothing. That ENV var is not set

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling on this, be sure that you didn't initialize transport with an empty struct. Here's the [DefaultTransport](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#RoundTripper) (note the `Proxy` value):

```golang
var DefaultTransport RoundTripper = &Transport{
    Proxy: ProxyFromEnvironment,
    DialContext: defaultTransportDialContext(&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    }),
    ForceAttemptHTTP2:     true,
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
}
```

So if you were to say something like:

```golang
if client.Transport == nil {
    client.Transport = &http.Transport{}
}
```

the proxy wouldn't be used. The fix for me was:

```golang
if client.Transport == nil {
    client.Transport = http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
}
```